# MacBook Pro MagSafe Charger - Kinks/Rings

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, magsafe

So for a while now, my MagSafe on my Mac has some sort of kinks/rings around the cable. This is only seen ABOVE the plastic thing used to tie in the cable when wrapping it, so around a 1-2 inch space below the MagSafe connector.

These kinks and rings have been there for a while now, and the charger still works, but I'm posting this now since it's starting to get worse. Should I be worried about taking it to Apple, or continue using it, and getting it checked out when something crazy happens (explosions lol))?

I have attached pictures below to show the wire of the MagSafe charger. It's ~ 2 years old.

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, bring it back to the Apple Store.. I bet they've never seen this before.

Comment: I have seen pictures on the Internet of this happening before. It might have been caused due to me wrapping the cable around the MagSafe a bit too tight. :/

Comment: Still, this shouldn't be happening. The cable will eventually crack on some point.

Comment: True. I guess I'll see to it when it cracks :/. I don't have any time to go to the Apple Store, and it still works. It's not gonna harm my computer, right?

Comment: Those rings *will* crack, especially when hit by objects. It's how my cable started to fray. The ring got wounded and split open after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to my previous chargers, but not quite this bad.

The reason is wrapping the wire too tight around the charger and moving the little hook back and forth.

It can't really be fixed and the cable will break and tear. You can try going to the Apple store for a replacement, but without extended warranty I failed.

Until it break/cracks there's no real danger, after it breaks there's a mild chance of shock. I've fixed mine with [Sugru](https://sugru.com/), any silicone putty would work. I've seen quite some people use gaffer tape and the like. There's also specialised shrink sleeve products to fix it.

After the plastic breaks and no fixes are applied, the inner cable might start to fray and eventually also fail.

[image: My Sugru fix]

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. I'll try not to tightly wrap it, and I have AppleCare for another year, so I might be able to get it replaced. Right now it just looks ugly, but other than that, nothing.

Comment: it'd probably happen anyway, but maybe later, i had it happen after 1, 2 and 3 years, also the plastic just dries out sometimes, it's apparently very hard to make these actually durable :)

Comment: Yeah, it started happening after a few months for me. It's been 2 years now. :/